# Chaining promises/Deferreds with .then() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 I have a function that returns a new `jQuery.Deferred()`. When I chain calls to this function using `deferred.then()`, based on the documentation, I would expect a given function to be called when the preceding function returns, and to receive the `jQuery.Deferred()` as input.

In practice a given function is called when the preceding function's `jQuery.Deferred()` is signaled with `deferred.resolve()`, and receives the value passed to `.resolve()`.

The actual behavior is what I want, but I'm worried I'm relying on undocumented/unsupported behavior, or that I've actually got a bug creating the illusion of what I want.

For example, given

```
function async_task(i) {
  console.log("Starting async_task(" + i + ")\n");
  var def = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("    finished " + i + "\n");
    def.resolve(i + 1);
  }, 1000);
  return def;
}

console.log("starting\n");
var p;
p = async_task(1);
p = p.then(async_task);
p = p.then(async_task);
p.then(function() {
  console.log("done\n");
});
```

the output is

```
starting
Starting async_task(1)
    finished 1
Starting async_task(2)
    finished 2
Starting async_task(3)
    finished 3
done
```

but I would expect

```
starting
Starting async_task(1)
    finished 1
Starting async_task(2)
Starting async_task([object Object])
done
    finished 2
    finished [object Object]
```

I can certainly imagine that jQuery is probing what the function passed to `.then()` returns, and if it's a deferred/promise doing what I want, but I can't find documentation supporting that idea.

Why do my expectations based on the documentation not agree with what I'm observing? Have I overlooked documentation? Is this undocumented behavior I shouldn't rely on? Do I actually have a bug?

Comment: Do you mean `.then()` instead of `.next()`?

Comment: GregL: You are correct, thank you. I've fixed it. Embarrassing, since the code examples were correct, so at least sometimes I was writing the correct thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just misread the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). Admittedly they could be written better.

The sentence you were missing is

> These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks, or they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks.

While not explained great by jQuery, this adoption ("unwrapping") of further promises is actually one of the outstanding [features of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572).

Comment: I'm pretty certain that an earlier version of [that page](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), or maybe somewhere else in the jQuery site made the point better. Otherwise how did I learn it? The almost throw-away words "... or they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks" is indeed not enough to make this very important point.